# I moved my site to another server, wp admin works so does the front page, but posts don't work

Tags: posts, database, wp-admin, migration

Pretty much summed up everything in the title. I can see the posts in wp admin, but when I hit the "View" link they return a 404 not found.

Do you have any idea why this is happening?

As a note: I only moved the site to another server. The domain is the same.

Comment: Did you also move `.htaccess` file. Visit and save your permalink structure once again.

Comment: The permalink structure was the problem. Thanks, Robert.

Answer (score 0):

This was solved. To close the question, I'll put Robert's answer here:

He suggested I move the .htaccess file. This wasn't a problem for me. The problem was the permalink structure. I changed it to the default one and then back again to my permalink setting. It worked. Thanks!